# SQL Server Agent after upgrade

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sql-server-agent

I upgraded SQL Server from 2016 to 2019. And after that the SQL Server Agent tries to start, but after 10 seconds it stops.

```
023-03-08 16:54:55 - ? [000] Event Global\sqlserverRecComplete opened
2023-03-08 16:54:55 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 15.0.2000.5 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 7328
2023-03-08 16:54:55 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is xxx
2023-03-08 16:54:55 - ! [150] SQL Server does not accept the connection (error: 233). Waiting for Sql Server to allow connections. Operation attempted was: Verify Connection On Start.
2023-03-08 16:55:09 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server '(local)'; SQLServerAgent cannot start
2023-03-08 16:55:09 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 233, SSL Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe. [SQLSTATE 08001] 
2023-03-08 16:55:09 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 233, Client unable to establish connection [SQLSTATE 08001] 
2023-03-08 16:55:09 - ! [382] Logon to server '(local)' failed (DisableAgentXPs)
2023-03-08 16:55:09 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

Should I upgrade or configure SQL Server Agent after the SQL Server upgrade or what is the problem?

I tried to start the service from SQL Server configuration manager, services and SSMS.

Comment: It says " SSL Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe." - how do you interpret that?

Comment: Are you sure sql server is even "up"?

Comment: Check so server pipe connection is enabled perhaps

Comment: Yes. It's up and server pipe is enabled.

Comment: Did you enable Agent xtended procs?

Comment: Yes, the Agent XPs value is 1

Comment: Have you checked the Client Config tool yet to see if you have a `(local)` alias defined? Could it be referencing the old instance by an incorrect port number or instance name?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the account being used for the SQL Server agent service, try to change the service account just for hit and trial. It is worth a try.